# System Process PID 4 Attempt to connect to Public IP using port 445

Tags: network, windows-10, smb

I was cross checking my environment and i found that System process PID 4 establishing Outbound connection to public IP using Port 445 is that a normal behavior?

```
OS: Windows 10 1909
System PID 4
Local Port: 54114
Remote Port: 445
Remote IP: 134.32.141.238
```

Comment: I did a `whois` lookup of 134.32.141.238, and I see that this IP address is assigned to Schlumberger Limited.  Port 445 is used for Microsoft networking and filesharing.  Do you work for Schlumberger, or do any business with Schlumberger, that requires you to share files with them?

Comment: No i dont use any public shares

Comment: So that i want to know what process cause this attempt but i only see that its associate with System process

Comment: Several malware processes have been known to use port 445 to spread.  See https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2017/05/smb-exploited-wannacry-use-of-eternalblue.html

Comment: Have you tried capturing the traffic with Wireshark to see what's in it?

Comment: Try to check the process in VirusTotal. Use Process Explorer and right-click on the process and select check 'VirusTotal'. If it has been seen before it will flag. 

Use Process Explorer also to check what program is running this process and from which path so it may help to identify if malicious or not.

Comment: Nothing looks suspicious the hash value is normal , after checking seems that i have a couple of attempts from same Process "SYSTEM" to different IP's , the Firewall is blocking those attempts but I'm trying to find what is causing this SMB attempt